# string length differ with other languages...not in English

Tags: php

I used this coding to shorten my testimonials on my site, works perfectly!. But now I have a problem it is... I have given the opportunity to users add their testimonials from their own language. My coding is working properly with English characters but not with other languages' characters.... can anyone tell me why it is????

```
   <?php
    $echo = $getFig["news_content"];
    if(strlen($echo) <= 100){
    $bar = $echo;
    }if(strlen($echo) > 100){
    $bar = substr($echo, 0, 101 )."<ahref='#'>Read More...</a>";
    }

    echo htmlspecialchars($bar);
    ?>
```

any comments are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `mb_*` functions. In your example [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) and [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php).

The reason is that `strlen` and `substr` will count bytes that are perfectly fine for ASCII characters but  some unicode characters allocate more than one byte so the result appears incorrect with [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) and `substr`. `mb_*` functions hide this issue perfectly while they count character-set, not a number of bytes.

For further information read the manual.

**EDIT:**

---

You can use [`str_word_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) to count how many words are there in string if you are interested more in words than in characters.

Sample:

```
$str = 'Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text';
echo str_word_count($str);
```

*Note:* If your target language has another delimiter than space for words, you can write custom function that will count occurrences of this delimiter in given string.

Comment: but my problem is still not solved. Actually I need to do here a long paragraph convert to short one with a read more link to original one. Is there a way to count words rather than characters...?

Comment: Still I have the problem.. I tried using sinhala language. like this... $sinhala ='තරංග නුවන්' the variable have only two words.. but when I echoing with str_word_count($sinhala) output given 11. why is it?

Comment: @TharangaNuwan can you give me a sample string?

Comment: this is a paragraph in sinhala

Comment: එය ඉතාමත් තෘප්තිමත් ශතකයක්. විශේෂයෙන්ම එය ලබාගත්තේ ඉතාමත් හොඳ පන්දු යැවීමේ බලඇණියකට එරෙහිව මෙන්ම අතිරේක ඉපිළීමක්ද සහිත  ඕස්ටේ‍්‍රලියානු තණතීරුවක් මත වීම නිසයි
තිලකරත්න ඩිල්ෂාන් - <a href="">ඕස්ටේ‍්‍රලියාවේදී </a>ලබාගත් පළමු වැනි ටෙස්ට් ශතකය සම්බන්ධයෙන් අදහස් දක්වමින්එය ඉතාමත් තෘප්තිමත් ශතකයක්. විශේෂයෙන්ම එය

Comment: can your see it in sinhala language?

Comment: @TharangaNuwan I can't. But as documentation says you have to pass sinhala characters as third parameter.

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Yn0dKE Here what I have tried with your string. Because I don't know that language, I have cheated :P. What you have to do is have string `$sinhalaAlphabet = 'characters of sinhala in format: abcde...';` and count words like: `str_word_count($sinhala, 0, $sinhalaAlphabet);`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22062/discussion-between-tharanga-nuwan-and-plb)

Comment: also `str_word_count()` dont work on Persian(Farsi) language.no one have any idea idea about how solve `str_word_count() `...this function dont work with Persian and Arabic character

Comment: @Mostafa It gets alphabet as an argument. For the languages, that are not supported you should pass the alphabet char list as the third argument

Answer (score 4):

See the note in the documentation:

> **Note:**
>
> strlen() returns the number of bytes rather than the number of
>   characters in a string.

[strlen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) returns the **byte count**, not the character count; the two are only the same for single byte character-sets.

Use [mb_strlen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) if you want the character length of a multi-byte character-set string such as UTF-8

Comment: Actually, `strlen` is [binary-safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-safe): “A binary-safe function is essentially one that treats its input as a raw stream of data without any specific format.”

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is occurring to the fact that strlen works on ascii characters, of which is English. An alternative is the mb_strlen.

Here is a sample code:

```
<?php 
$str = "Some user input こんにちわ";
$len = mb_strlen($str);
```

This is just a sample to illustrate what I am trying to say, but I hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

`strlen` and `substr` assume single-byte characters. They rather work on byte basis than on character basis.

For multi-byte characters, you should use the [multi-byte string](http://php.net/book.mbstring) counterparts `mb_strlen` and `mb_substr`. [They support a variety of character encodings](http://php.net/mbstring.encodings).